# How can I make my laptop use more memory then it can take

Tags: memory

I have an old Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600,the max memory it can take is 512mb
The question is, What can I do to increase memory as although an old machine is still very servicable.

I have tried increasing pagefile size, which has helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS, if Microsoft windows then the limit may be in the OS.

Comment: Just looked it up on toshiba's web site apparently this is the max. Also, you mention pagefile size this is swap file size (on microsoft windows), You can increase it to around 3GB, it will allow you to run applications that use a lot of memory, but it will do nothing about the amount of RAM, so these application will probably run slow, because they will swap a lot.

Comment: If you just want it to run better (faster), then I would recommend replacing the operating system with Vector Gnu/Linux. Vector is a distribution of Gnu/Linux optimised for older machines, but that are at least pentium class (such as yours).

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum physical memory it can take is 512, then there is nothing you can do, but if you can swap that out for a stick that's say a gig or 2 then that's all you need to do.

Aside from that I'm afraid there's nothing you can do if this is a physical hardware constraint.

Comment: -1 for saying you have nothing to say, and telling us what the questioner already knows.